# How can I prevent all Windows 10 Telemetry?

Tags: windows, privacy, data-leakage, windows-10, sensitive-data-exposure

Let's assume I'm connecting to a network, and I need absolutely no data sent to any Microsoft servers at any time. Is there a way to do that? For the sake of argument, assume I'm running Enterprise.

Comment: Do you still want to be able to run (automatic?) updates?

Comment: I'll just use WSUS Offline, or Windows Update Minitool.

Comment: Get Spybot Anti-Beacon for telemetry without preventing updates. Also, nearly every single program you run tries to phone home to choice.microsoft.com

Answer (score 1):

Set up a proxy/firewall between you and the outside world. Add a white list of good servers to the proxy. This is very restrictive but the only way to guarantee it (except have no network). A black list could work, but there are **always** ways around.

Comment: @r3muxd I know. I am just expressing that the only way to block it is not subtle. You have no idea what is in the software, so you have to sandbox it. This means isolating it from everything that you do not fully trust.

Comment: [WindowsSpyBlocker](https://github.com/crazy-max/WindowsSpyBlocker) can be used for this purpose. It has a great set of rules (spy, update and extra) in many format (OpenWRT, DNSCrypt, P2P, Proxifier...) and is updated frequently.

Comment: Any software running on the untrusted platform, can **at best** block known telemetry. Even a firewall could be circumvented, if you allow arbitrary web access (by tunnelling data through cooperating web servers).